# Printing values from a multidimensional array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a block of data which I define as a range ("ARRAY_DIM") in excel. The range includes a lot of data but also have many rows and columns with no data at all. Below is an example of the defined range. Please note that the number of data columns for each identifier varies which is why the ARRAY_DIM is defined with +100 columns (of which only few rows will contain data).

```
Banana  10  20  30  40  50  70
Parrot  5       1   4   30
Apple   3   3   5   6       20
Car     10  20  30  40  30
Donkey  4   12  3   0   4   5
Coconut     10      4   0   1
```

I am inserting all of this data into an array such that I can loop through a list of relevant identifiers and then paste the data associated with the identifiers in the adjacent cells (same row). See below for a simplified example of identifiers (first column is a range defined as "OUTPUT") and where I intend to paste the relevant data for identifiers that are included in the array.

```
Banana  10  20  30  40  50  70
SHARK 
Apple   3   3   5   6       20
Airplane
```

I am having troubles with accomplishing this task based on the code below. It works fine for the first row/identifier but then I get an error "Subscript out of range" at the .Cells output line. I would appreciate if someone can review the code and maybe point out any errors.

```
Sub test()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim cell As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    arr = .Range("ARRAY_DIM")
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Each cell In .Range("OUTPUT")
        For x = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If arr(x, 1) = cell.Value Then
                For n = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                    .Cells(cell.Row, n + 2) = arr(x, n + 1)
                Next n
            End If
        Next x
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably the `n+1` is throwing the error, because you've let `n` have a maximum value of the `arr`'s upper bound, so `arr(x, n+1)` is by definition out of range.

Comment: So I'm guessing you have the original data in one order and then you want to fill another table with the same elements from the original in a different order?

Comment: FWIW, row/column iteration like this seems unnecessary. Let me tinker on an alternative solution.

Comment: Hi. This macro is used in a larger context to transfer data from one workbook to another (It is sort of an update type sub). @David Zemens: I understand your point and would appreciate if you can suggest how to revise the macro.

Comment: I'll leave it to @DavidZemens then, this is easy to  code with a dictionary indexing the position of every identifier inside the array.

Answer (score 2):

This should handle it, assuming unique labels in the first columns:

```
Dim data As Object
Dim r As Range
Dim thisName As String
Dim thisData As Range
Set data = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Store each row in our Dictionary with key=item name, value=row values
    For Each r In .Range("ARRAY_DIM").Rows
        Set data(r.Cells(1).Value) = r.Resize(1, r.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1)
    Next
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Each r In .Range("OUTPUT").Columns(1).Cells
        thisName = r.Cells(1).Value
        ' Check if thisName exists in our Dictionary
        If data.Exists(thisName) Then
            ' Dump the data into the row if it exists
            Set thisData = data(thisName)
            r.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, thisData.Columns.Count).Value = thisData.Value
        End If
    Next
End With
```

But I think that can be further simplified to a single loop:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim thisName As String
Dim thisData As Range
Dim outputRow As Variant
Dim outputRange as Range
Set outputRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("OUTPUT")
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ARRAY_DIM")
    For Each r In .Rows
        thisName = r.Cells(1).Value
        ' Check whether thisName exists in outputRange
        outputRow = Application.Match(thisName, outputRange, False)
        If Not IsError(outputRow) Then
            ' Dump this row's Values to the outputRange
            outputRange.Rows(outputRow).Value = r.Value
        End If
    Next
End With
```

NB: Neither of the above approaches will *add* a new row if the `thisName` isn't found in the OUTPUT range.